# iPad Safari reloads main page constantly

Tags: ios, http, networking

Our Webapp site has strange problem where we get occasionally huge number of page reloads from Apple iPad Safari.

What happens is that Safari opens keep alive HTTP 1.1 connection to our server and issue streams of GETs to it. The requests can arrive only tens of milliseconds from each other and it seems Safari is reloading the page as soon as it gets response to previous request. After sending 4-5 requests, Safari closes socket, opens new and same thing repeats for several minutes until it suddenly stops.

Things checked

- Happens only with main page root url /
- Page has no window.location.reload call on load that could cause this
- Confirmed with tcpdump and wireshark that problem is real and happens between iPad device and our server. (i.e. not problem with haproxy, our servers or buggy logging)
- Problem seems to be mainly with iOS 4.3.3
- I can not ask the users and we have not repeated this locally with testing devices
- All problem requests come from single IP that seems like VPN gateway of a school but from different random users (based on cookies same users may use webapp days successfully until problem repeats)

Has anyone idea what might be happening here?

- Broken proxy somehwere?
- iOS HomeScreen webapp bookmark gone haywire?
- DoS attempt, though lame one
- People turn zombies while using our webapp and instead of Brainsss they crave Reloadss?